# Invalid number of parameters for " ". Got 0 expected 2!

Tags: solidity, truffle

I have the function below which doesn't take any arguments when i call it from truffle console i get the below error, any idea on how i can fix this:

```
uint ownerCounter = 0;

function getNumberOfTokenOwners() public view onlyOwner returns ( uint ) {
    return ownerCounter;
}
```

> Thrown:
>   Error: Invalid number of parameters for "getNumberOfTokenOwners". Got 0 expected 2!
>       at Object._createTxObject (/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:699:1)
>       at Object.InvalidNumberOfParams (/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-contract/~/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:32:1)

i am using

> Truffle v5.0.19 (core: 5.0.19) Solidity - 0.5.2 (solc-js) Node v12.3.1
>   Web3.js v1.0.0-beta.37

Comment: Try remove build folder and then compile it again. This solution work for me

Answer (score 3):

As @haxerl suggested, deleting the build folder and recompiling again fixed the issue.